# How to use Glyphicons Pro in simple Meteor App?

Tags: meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I don't know how to use Glypicons Pro in simple Meteor App:

1. `meteor create meteor-intro`
2. `cd meteor-intro`
3. `meteor`  (to run the app and it works fine)
4. `meteor add bootstrap-3`
5. copy these folders of files into meteor-intro app folder
    Downloads\glyphicons_pro\glyphicons_pro\glyphicons\web\html_css\css
    Downloads\glyphicons_pro\glyphicons_pro\glyphicons\web\html_css\fonts
    Downloads\glyphicons_pro\glyphicons_pro\glyphicons\web\html_css\images
6. replace content of meteor-intro.html with the following:

   ```
   <head>
     <title>meteor-intro</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css?v=2">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/glyphicons.css">
   </head>

   <body>
     <h2>Fonts</h2>
     <div class="list list-fonts c">
       <a href="" class="glyphicons glass"><strong>glass</strong><span>UTF E001</span></a>
           <a href="" class="glyphicons server_new"><strong>server_new</strong><span>UTF E470</span></a>
     </div>
   </body>
   ```

Meteor App runs but glyphicons are not rendered. How can I get them to render??

Comment: Sorry... I also don't know how to include the HTML code snippet above without out it rendering as HTML :(

Comment: @gdbMeteor no problem. Found here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should place the fonts and images in your Meteor /public folder, and then change the relative path of the url in the `@font-face` property of the glyphicons .css file to point to their location.

So if your new relative file path from your main Meteor app folder becomes `public/glyphicons_pro/glyphicons/web/html_css/fonts`, change the `@font-face` property to correspond to the location in the public folder:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Regular';
  src:
    url('/glyphicons_pro/glyphicons/web/html_css/fonts/glyphicons-regular.eot');
  src:
    url('/glyphicons_pro/glyphicons/web/html_css/fonts/glyphicons-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('/glyphicons_pro/glyphicons/web/html_css/fonts/glyphicons-regular.woff') format('woff'),
    url('/glyphicons_pro/glyphicons/web/html_css/fonts/glyphicons-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('/glyphicons_pro/glyphicons/web/html_css/fonts/glyphicons-regular.svg#glyphiconsregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

You should place the .css file in a part of your Meteor directory where it is only served on the client side.

*And also remove the links from your  - the files are loaded automatically within your app once they are placed in the appropriate directories.

Comment: Your answer works! *I added a /client/stylesheets folder for glyphicons.css (fixed the paths) and style.css, and left the other glyphicon stuff in /public.  This allowed me to remove the links in meteor-intro.html and remove the css folder in /public.  Cheers!